# How can I specify the locale as a URI segment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I have my applitation multilanguage now, but i'm using params, ex: www.example.com?locale=es. I like to migrate this to www.example.com/es/ ... i'm triying adding :prefix_path => :locale to routes but not works.

Any suggestion to better way to implement this ?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

Answer (score 0):

I fix it adding

```
  def default_url_options(options={})
         { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end
```

in application controller.